# Missing Feature when applying a MSP patch

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, msi-patch

We have a piece of software that's installed with Installshield, currently at version 5.0.1.

Between the version 4.9 and 5.0.0, a new Installshield Feature, REDIST, containing Redistribuables, was added to the Installshield project. The version 5.0 is delivered as a msi, which can be installed alone or upgrade an existing 4.9 installation. We're currently working on the version 5.0.1, which is delivered as a patch (.msp). The patch is a Minor Upgrade, since the Product Code is the same as in version 5.0.0. This patch can be installed at the time of the 5.0 installation, with the `PATCH` property on the command line.

When installing 5.0 and the 5.0.1 patch at the same time (`msiexec /i "5.0.0.msi" PATCH="5.0.1.msp"`) on an existing 4.9, the Feature REDIST is not installed (in the install log: `Feature: REDIST; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null`). The issue does not appear when the 5.0.0 and 5.0.1 are installed separately.

I don't have much experience with Installshield, so I think I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: No time to look at this now, but maybe you need to use ADDLOCAL to add the new feature? You might need to list all features you want to install, I am not sure. I don't use patching much, and the PATCH property with the /I parameter I have never used at all. [Maybe have a look under "Upgrading Without Patching"](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/updates.htm). The REINSTALL / ADDLOCAL issue. I would try to list all features in ADDLOCAL first.

Comment: And some thoughts on [minor upgrades in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130). I would assume your team is all up to date on these issues.

Comment: Minor upgrades and patching require Jedi like Windows Installer skills. I  recommend starting with Major Upgrades.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Thank you for your answer. I tried `ADDLOCAL=ALL,REDIST` and the REDIST Feature was still not installed.

Comment: I would check what the log file says, and I am not sure you can combine ALL and a feature name. Maybe try to list all features that are to be installed or reinstalled?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Ok. But I don't know when I'll test this since it's low priority and my boss asked me to switch to the current critical bug. Thank you still.

Comment: Word of advice with regards to patching: don't use it unless you absolutely have to, and if you have to then make the patch as simple as possible, preferably just a couple of files. Some comments on patching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450821/129130) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187180/129130).