# MSI OriginalDatabase and SourceDir properties and replacing MSI file

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I place update.msi file let's say in C:\installs and run it. After some time I replace update.msi and repeat installation (sometimes it is the same application - updated, and sometimes completely different one).

From MSI log files I can notice it keeps track of OriginalDatabase, SourceDir, properties.
Can this have any implications when for example I want to uninstall one of the applications installed in a described way?

Comment: Are you using a major upgrade to replace the previous version? You are not modifying the original MSI directly and then re-installing it are you? You should build new MSI files from sources, not hot-fix existing MSI Files. Not sure that is what you are doing. MSI keeps track of everything you install, including the location of the original installation database. In most cases the original source is not required for uninstall, but there are some technical pitfalls that can trigger the need for the original installation media. [**Some details here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010825/129130).

Comment: MSI files are always built from sources. Let's say that there were pitfalls and we need the original installation file. Is this file searched by path and name (C:\installs\update.msi) or is there any checksum or some id related to exactly source MSI file?

Comment: You need the exact same MSI that was used to install - specifically the **package code** identifies the original file uniquely. There are also some [**caching features**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823086/129130) in modern deployment tools so you could find the original installer cached in various places. Please see that previous link for a description. There is also [a longer description of MSI file caching here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189524/129130) - quite messy, but should be accurate.