# Squid proxy - Windows silent/automated installation

Tags: windows, windows-installer, squid, silent-installer

Is there a way to install Squid proxy on window silently? 
It's an msi installer, and I tried the silent install option for msi

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ilikesql_by_dandyman/2013/03/10/how-to-install-a-msi-file-unattended/

```
/qn
/quiet
```

It did install partially and did not work. 
Does anyone know the right way to do this? Is there a command line installer? something like apt-get in linux? or chocolatey? anything that works wil be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
MSIEXEC /i squid.msi /qn /log install_log.txt ROOTDRIVE=C:\
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. Some MSI files with **design flaws** can cause an incomplete install when run silently. The cause of this is attempted explained here: [**Uninstall from Control Panel is different from Remove from .msi**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677483/uninstall-from-control-panel-is-different-from-remove-from-msi/29679464#29679464). Essentially certain custom actions may be run only from the GUI, and may be skipped entirely when running silently. **This is a serious design flaw**, and should obviously not happen in a good MSI setup.