# How to tag or customize the a binary (for example of an installer)

Tags: windows-installer, installation

How can I tag or modify a .msi binary with custom information?

How can I give website users individual downloads, so that they don't have to sign in again in the app?

Some websites offer personal/customized/tagged installer downloads.

When you run the file, the executeable already knows who you are and automatically signs you in.

Examples are:

- join.me where passing the presenter role, triggers a download for the other party and automatically connects them into the right conference
- spotify had a download, that would not need you to sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameterize an MSI file so that it can install with different settings based on the values you pass to it via the `msiexec.exe` command line. The install you kick off can run silently or interactively based on what `msiexec.exe` switches you define.

You can **auto-generate the command lines** in question directly from a web-page using Javascript, or in some other fashion. You can also customize the MSI using a more advanced option: **transforms**.

Rather than rewriting it all, I will link to a previous answer which describes how to use **PUBLIC PROPERTIES** set at the `msiexec.exe` command line or **transforms** to modify settings in MSI files during installation: **[How to make better use of MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861)** (a little long, but the first section is all that is relevant in your case).

1. Sample command line you can auto-generate using **PUBLIC PROPERTIES**:

```dos
msiexec.exe /i "MySetup.msi" /L*v "%TMP%\MyLog.log" SERIALKEY="123-456-789" EMAIL="myemail@somedomain.com" LOGINNAME="MyLogin" LOGINPASSWORD="MyPassword"
```

Obviously think twice about pushing the password via command line.

2. Sample command line you can auto-generate using **transforms**:

```dos
msiexec.exe /i "MySetup.msi" /L*v "%TMP%\MyLog.log" TRANSFORMS="MyTransform.mst"
```

Inside `MyTransform.mst` you can change and override almost anything you want inside the whole MSI file - including setting the properties from the first sample in the Property Table.

And you can [**auto-generate the transform itself using the MSI API**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368251(v=vs.85).aspx). I will dig up a better link when I have a moment.

**UPDATE**: there is [a whole family of sample VBScripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372865(v=vs.85).aspx) showing how to use the MSI API in various ways. The [**widiffdb.vbs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372504(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how to generate a transform (among other things). And there is a sample dedicated to just creating a transform: [**wigenxfm.vbs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

***These scripts should be installed with Visual Studio and the SDK***. Maybe email a friend (one with lots of patience!) with this installed and have them zip it for you if you are in a rush, or install the whole shebang yourself.

The MSI API can be accessed with Javascript, but I have experienced some clunky issues that are a little too detailed to explain. VBScript was used to test the object model, and hence seems to work better.

It should be possible to [invoke Windows Installer from an URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367817(v=vs.85).aspx). So they tell me. Good luck with that :-). I tried about 17 years ago and abandoned it. Perhaps it is better now.

---

And some similar answers (this question keeps coming up):

- [How to push MSI with parameter using SCCM server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754283/how-to-push-msi-with-parameter-using-sccm-server?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- [How to make better use of MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861).
- [Advantages of Transforms(mst) over msi file](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=17214).

Comment: Thanks @Stein, I've played with the Orca Tool to test these transforms. Unfortunately I'll have to sign the exectutables after making any changes. So I'll have to sign all of them :-(

Comment: Are these OEM version? Could you use properties only?

Comment: What do you mean with OEM version? We compile our own binaries and we could sign each one, but this would make the pipeline more complicated so I'm looking for simpler solutions. What do you mean with "Properties"?

Comment: [OEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer) is basically when you let other companies do the marketing for your product. They sell your product as their own and the OEM setup you provide them shows their logo and contact info, etc... For example a major software reseller - they get percentages for selling your software. With "Properties" I refer to the input value you can send to an MSI via the command line: `msiexec.exe /i Setup.msi PROPERTY1="Value" PROPERTY2="Value" PROPERTY3="Value"` etc... As many properties as you need.