# How to point MSI to license server?

Tags: windows-installer, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have an ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1 msi which installs however I receive an error when I test the app as it needs to be pointed to the license server:

Current command:
msiexec /i "setup.msi" /q

For Example, say my server is named BC-FF12

Which parameter would I use to point here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Documentation***: You have to acquire documentation from the vendor to work out complex aspects of deployment: https://www.itninja.com/link/license-manager-reference-guide

---

***"Software / Packaging Tips"***: I also like to check for ["software tips"](https://www.itninja.com/software-library) on sites like this:
**https://www.itninja.com/software/esri/arcgis-1/10-1344** (**`be sure to visit this link`**)

There seems to be a number of MSI properties that should be set for this install to function correctly:

```
ESRI_LICENSE_HOST=<licensing server name>
SOFTWARE_CLASS=Viewer or Editor or Professional (depending on your licensing type)
SEAT_PREFERENCE=Fixed or Float (depending on your licensing type) 
REBOOT=ReallySuppress
RestartYesNo=No
ISCHECKFORPRODUCTUPDATES=0
DESKTOP_CONFIG=TRUE
```

There also seems to be a **`*.prvc`** license file of some sort that they suggest to invoke as follows (there are often different ways to do this kind of thing - and **I would be surprised if you need to do this if you use a license server** - if it is properly set up - something like this command might need to be run on the server):

```
CD "C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\"
SoftwareAuthorization.exe -s -LIF "C:\Users\pcsetup\Desktop\ArcGis-10\ArcInfo.prvc"
```

I have not tested, but in your case it might be sufficient to set the properties via msiexec.exe command lines - I would test on a virtual:

```
Msiexec.exe /I <dir>\Desktop\setup.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL ESRI_LICENSE_HOST="Hostname" SOFTWARE_CLASS=Editor /qb
```

They suggest to use Orca to set a number of these properties in a transform (a file used to modify vendor MSI settings).

***Transforms vs Properties***: [MSI installation customization via msiexec.exe commands with or without the use of transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58232330/129130).

If you make a transform to apply to the MSI - as described in the link just above - you apply it via the command line for installation:

```
msiexec.exe /i setup.msi TRANSFORMS="mytransform.mst" /qn
```