# What is, for Wix, the difference between pressing the uninstall button of an installer and uninstalling via Apps&Features?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I have an application with a Wix installer. When the user uninstalls without the installer executable but just uses the [Apps&Features inside windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/apps-features-settings-in-windows-10), how does that differ? Because it seems that some custom actions are not executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't check this right now, but please check if [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29679464/129130) has any clues. Essentially the setup might be run in silent mode when invoked from Apps & Features (it is run silently from the old ARP - Add / Remove Programs), and this affects a lot of things - perhaps most significantly conditions set for custom actions and such things.

Answer (score 0):

When user uninstalls from Apps&Features, interactive part(InstallUISequence) of installer is skipped. Check if affected custom action is scheduled in InstallUISequence only or if custom action condition contains **UILevel** property. Also, search msi log for affected custom actions if it's present and its displaying **(condition is false)**. This would mean the problem is with custom action condition only.

Custom actions needs to be sequenced in InstallExecuteSequence table if this needs to be executed every time irrespective of whether its interactive or silent un-installation.

Depending on your requirements, you might schedule in both install sequences.