# start wmi_exporter with task scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-installer

I scheduled a task at system startup to run the "msi" file of wmi_exporter with argument LISTEN_PORT=9100. Task is expected to install msi and listen on 9100 port however no installation process occur upon trigger of scheduled task. I can see the task running in task manager.

Note: you can refer to [this](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter) page if you want to know what wmi_exporter is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you schedule it to run in silent mode? If not it could be stuck on a setup dialog being shown (running in a logon session you can not see). There are also other possibilities. What user did you set to launch the scheduled task?

Here is a sample `msiexec.exe` command line to install the MSI file silently:

```
msiexec.exe /I "enterprise_gsync.msi" /QN /L*V "msilog.log"
```

I don't want to duplicate a previous answer of mine on superuser.com, please open it here: [**How to deploy MSI which has no silence install switch?**](https://superuser.com/questions/1243008/how-to-deploy-msi-which-has-no-silence-install-switch/1248364#1248364) (**`this answer elaborates and explains the above command line`**).

---

***Some Links***:

- [How can I silently install an MSI package using msiexec installer with a list of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170763/how-can-i-silently-install-an-msi-package-using-msiexec-installer-with-a-list-of/49172756#49172756)
- [Tool to build msiexec.exe command line](https://serverfault.com/questions/30068/silent-install-of-msi/67001#67001)
- [installation using msi.exec open help options every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164005/installation-using-msi-exec-open-help-options-every-time?lq=1)
  -[msiexec parameters via setup.exe to create log not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783396/msiexec-parameters-via-setup-exe-to-create-log-not-working)
- [Uninstall from Control Panel is different from Remove from .msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677483/uninstall-from-control-panel-is-different-from-remove-from-msi/29679464#29679464)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did try  the /QN switch however not the "/I" switch. Also, I directly invoked the msi file not through msiexec.exe `D:\cr_monitoring\wmi_exporter-0.4.2-amd64.msi /Q LISTEN_PORT=9100`. This is what I was trying