# Multiple Project Optional Install MSI

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer, installation

I have written several add-ins For Office and depending on the user, would like to install certain add-ins, I am not opposed to writing this from scratch, however, before attempting to do so, I would rather find out if there are other options available.

The following things are required
The add-ins do alter the registry
A single installer with optional install of each add-in

The following things are not an issue
Files can be installed to Parent Folder i.e
 C:\Program Files (x86)*Company**Program Group*\Program\

I have looked into this, and have not found anything for optional installation of multiple programs. Especially given that the registry will be edited for each of the add-ins.

There is one possible option I have thought of and that is to install everything, and only make the registry conditional, thus allowing the user to only activate the programs.

p.s. I apologize if my wording is awkward, I am not very good with words.

Comment: Advanced Installer is an option, but probably not the best given that I may not have to install every add-in for every user.

Comment: Been ages since I did addins, where in the registry do you enable / disable them? Is it HKCU or HKLM? You can use MSI features to enable or disable certain things for the installation. Lobbing some links for now: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055861/129130), [2](https://superuser.com/a/785825/11906).

Comment: HKCU, but I would like to package all of the add-ins I create for various people in one installer, and then select the add-ins to install for them, I know how to edit the registry, but It would be best if i did not install any unneeded add-ins for the purpose of saving space.

Comment: @cdickstein write us an email at support@advancedinstaller.com, mentioning me. If I am not available one of my colleagues will take a closer look and help you. In the first phase, we need to better understand your scenario, to make sure you're not overengineering the MSI

Comment: I have actually decided to install each program individually after speaking to the potential users. This give me more control, and does limit the amount of install data.