# I use an old set of 3rd party controls, Janus Systems WinForms Controls looking for silent install instructions

Tags: windows-installer, janus

We are looking to begin using CI/CD on Azure DevOps - via GitHub - but these controls need to have the license activated on the box running the compile.

It's an MSI file that does this. I know I can run 
`msiexec /i C:\setup.msi [package_parameters] /qn /norestart`

But I don't know what the `[package_parameters]` might be. I was hoping someone out there had any ideas.

Comment: The answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861) might be helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question as defined by the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)